# Creating Table from Comma Separated String in Hive

Tags: hive

I have the following data:

```
1    'a'  
2    'b'  
3    'c'  
3    'd'
```

And I wanted to create a table in hive, from that data, with the following columns:

```
map | value  
1   |  a  
2   |  b  
3   |  c  
3   |  d
```

There is a restriction on the starting data type, which has to be a string. From there onward, I can manipulate the data structure however I want. (the starting input has to be a string type)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear. What is the type of `{1:a,2:b,3:c,d}`? What is `one-to-many mapping`? Please give an example that correctly describes your scenario

Comment: So, my input can only be a string type, therefore, {1:a,2:b,3:c,d} will be a string. Which can be converted to a map using str_to_map. However since, 3 is mapped to two values 'c' and 'd', I can't use this anymore.

An alternate approach could be passing two comma separated strings which would be converted to two arrays.
{1,2,3,3}
{a,b,c,d}
And then I'll have to insert these values in a table to get the required result.

Comment: I can rephrase my requirement. Is it possible to insert values to a column in a table from an array?
For example, {1,2,3,3} being inserted into the table should give the following one-column table:

1
2
3
3

Comment: Please read the following link and than ask again, this time by describing how is your source data looks like and how is the requested result looks like. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Not on comments please, just edit your post

Comment: I've edited the post. Is that better?

Comment: Why not save the file in CSV/TSV format? from there it is straight forward